# Get Index of dataframe 1 to dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

Dataframe 1

annualGrammy

Dataframe2

annualGrammy Song

I would like to get the index of Dataframe 1 in Dataframe 2 as a new column if annualGrammy matches. Do I need to merge?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have

```
df1 = df1 = pd.DataFrame({"annualGrammy":[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]}, index=["i1","i2", "i3","i4","i5","i6","i7","i8"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"annualGrammy":[11,16,17,110,111], "song": ["a","b","c","d","e"]})
```

Such that

```
df1.reset_index()

    annualGrammy    index
0   11              i1
1   12              i2
2   13              i3
3   14              i4
4   15              i5
5   16              i6
6   17              i7
7   18              i8
```

and

```
df2

    annualGrammy    song
0   11              a
1   16              b
2   17              c
3   110             d
4   111             e
```

The, you can merge using `how="left"` to keep track of index on `df1`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="annualGrammy", how="left")

    index   annualGrammy    song
0   i1      11              a
1   i2      12              NaN
2   i3      13              NaN
3   i4      14              NaN
4   i5      15              NaN
5   i6      16              b
6   i7      17              c
7   i8      18              NaN
```

All `NaN`s are values that are not a match in `ag`. You can drop them to get only values that matter

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="annualGrammy", how="left").dropna()

    annualGrammy    index   song
0   11              i1      a
5   16              i6      b
6   17              i7      c
```

Answer (score 0):

If `annualGrammy` in `df1` is unique, you can also use `map` to create a new column in `df2`. Using the data provided by RafaelC

```
import pandas as pd

dct = pd.Series(df1.index.values, df1.annualGrammy.values).to_dict()
df2['index'] = df2.annualGrammy.map(dct)
df2 = df2.dropna()
```

`df2` is now

```
   annualGrammy song index
0            11    a    i1
1            16    b    i6
2            17    c    i7
```